# http package times out under Flutter but works fine with just Dart, why?

Tags: flutter, http, timeout

The http package works just fine in a Dart program.  I created a class that does the I/O and it worked fine.  The unit tests run with no problem.  When trying to make use of the class in a Flutter program, it just hangs and eventually times out.

In the documentation I found a complete example of doing http I/O.  In the https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data-page at the bottom is a Complete example of doing http I/O in Flutter (see below).  I created a new Flutter Project and loaded the code into it.  It hangs up and times out just like my own classes.  I tried several different URL's, but they all time out.

I've updated all the AndroidManifest.xml  for android - debug, main and profile with: ''

It does not matter if it's a get or a put, it just times out.  Any ideas?

Here is the "Complete example' from the Flutter Documentation:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  const Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'] as int,
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```